# How to print in C# - but not through crystal-report?

Tags: c#

How to print in C# - but not through crystal-report?

Can I get some simple sample code?

Comment: How to print what? Self-drawn text/graphics? Images? Documents of any kind (PDF, Word, Open Office)? Data extracted from a database? Please clarify!

Comment: Is this for web or windows app?

Comment: how to print Data from DataBase in WinForm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class.

There's also a good tutorial here:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic44330.htm

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it's link only. It would be great to see a code sample in here (yes, I understand this answer is from 2010, but still.)

Answer (score -2):

this may be wrong because i'm dumb founded by the last part but to print you type "Console.WriteLine("whatever ur gonna print");"

Comment: I believe the OP means 'print' as in printing a physical paper, or printing to a PDF.